# Querying in SQL Alchemy Using Conjuctions

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, conjunctive-normal-form

I am trying to take a list of strings and query based an or combination of all the strings in the list. I want to know if something like this can be done below.

```
def filters(self,filter_company = ["DPL"]):
print "TEST"
        # Company Filter
        company_conj = 1        ## Bitwise 1 with AND will not effect other AND bits
        for c in filter_company:
            company_conj = (company_conj) & (Exception.company == c)            ## Create co


    qrty_exceptions = session.query(Exception).filter(company_conj)         ## Query by conjunction
```

So basically, I am iterating through each item in the list and trying to make a conjunction by concatinating. The point being is that I don't know how many items will be in the list...but I want to logically bitwise AND them together so they all form the conjunction. I end up getting the following error:

TypeError: unsuported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and BinaryExpression

In reality, I mean't to write this using the bitwise OR symbol... "|" but i figure if you can do it for AND then it should work for OR too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the example below should help you:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_

company_filters = ["Filter1", "Filter2"]  # as many as you like

clauses = [(Exception.company == c) for c in company_filters]
q = session.query(Exception)
q = q.filter(and_(*clauses))  # or `or_(*clauses)`
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked and I ended up extending it to:  q = q.filter(and_(or_(*clauses),or_(*other_clauses))). I never thought of using the asterisk multiple parameter's symbol to pass in multiple arguments.